# How to find if my app use more memory than optimal?

Tags: android, memory-management

My app is playing video clips and continues audio playback after going to background.

```
Applications Memory Usage (kB):
Uptime: 2572430 Realtime: 2572430

** MEMINFO in pid 11771 [bigdig.yarh.ellotv.activitytry] **
                         Shared  Private     Heap     Heap     Heap
                   Pss    Dirty    Dirty     Size    Alloc     Free
                ------   ------   ------   ------   ------   ------
       Native       20       12       20   167508   126691      120
       Dalvik    46565    11536    46336    50932    45645     5287
       Cursor        0        0        0                           
       Ashmem        0        0        0                           
    Other dev       52       56        0                           
     .so mmap     3145     2536     1012                           
    .jar mmap        0        0        0                           
    .apk mmap     1269        0        0                           
    .ttf mmap       46        0        0                           
    .dex mmap     5018        0       84                           
   Other mmap    20096    32836     2784                           
      Unknown   125113      260   125112                           
        TOTAL   201324    47236   175348   218440   172336     5407

 Objects
               Views:      643         ViewRootImpl:        1
         AppContexts:        5           Activities:        2
              Assets:       63        AssetManagers:       63
       Local Binders:       17        Proxy Binders:       26
    Death Recipients:        1
     OpenSSL Sockets:        7

 SQL
         MEMORY_USED:      160
  PAGECACHE_OVERFLOW:       17          MALLOC_SIZE:       62

 DATABASES
      pgsz     dbsz   Lookaside(b)          cache  Dbname
         4       40             20         0/15/1  /data/data/bigdig.yarh.ellotv.activitytry/databases/webview.db

 Asset Allocations
    zip:/data/app/bigdig.yarh.ellotv.activitytry-1.apk:/assets/fonts/ubuntu_r.ttf: 346K
    zip:/data/app/bigdig.yarh.ellotv.activitytry-1.apk:/assets/fonts/ubuntu_r.ttf: 346K
    zip:/data/app/bigdig.yarh.ellotv.activitytry-1.apk:/assets/fonts/ubuntu_l.ttf: 406K
    zip:/data/app/bigdig.yarh.ellotv.activitytry-1.apk:/assets/fonts/ubuntu_r.ttf: 346K
    zip:/data/app/bigdig.yarh.ellotv.activitytry-1.apk:/assets/fonts/ubuntu_l.ttf: 406K
    zip:/data/app/bigdig.yarh.ellotv.activitytry-1.apk:/assets/fonts/ubuntu_r.ttf: 346K
    zip:/data/app/bigdig.yarh.ellotv.activitytry-1.apk:/assets/fonts/ubuntu_l.ttf: 406K
    zip:/data/app/bigdig.yarh.ellotv.activitytry-1.apk:/assets/fonts/ubuntu_r.ttf: 346K
    zip:/data/app/bigdig.yarh.ellotv.activitytry-1.apk:/assets/fonts/ubuntu_r.ttf: 346K
    zip:/data/app/bigdig.yarh.ellotv.activitytry-1.apk:/assets/fonts/ubuntu_r.ttf: 346K
    zip:/data/app/bigdig.yarh.ellotv.activitytry-1.apk:/assets/fonts/ubuntu_r.ttf: 346K
    zip:/data/app/bigdig.yarh.ellotv.activitytry-1.apk:/assets/fonts/ubuntu_r.ttf: 346K
    zip:/data/app/bigdig.yarh.ellotv.activitytry-1.apk:/assets/fonts/ubuntu_r.ttf: 346K
    zip:/data/app/bigdig.yarh.ellotv.activitytry-1.apk:/assets/fonts/ubuntu_r.ttf: 346K
    zip:/data/app/bigdig.yarh.ellotv.activitytry-1.apk:/assets/fonts/ubuntu_r.ttf: 346K
    zip:/data/app/bigdig.yarh.ellotv.activitytry-1.apk:/assets/fonts/ubuntu_r.ttf: 346K
    zip:/data/app/bigdig.yarh.ellotv.activitytry-1.apk:/assets/fonts/ubuntu_l.ttf: 406K
    zip:/data/app/bigdig.yarh.ellotv.activitytry-1.apk:/assets/fonts/ubuntu_r.ttf: 346K
    zip:/data/app/bigdig.yarh.ellotv.activitytry-1.apk:/assets/fonts/ubuntu_l.ttf: 406K
    zip:/data/app/bigdig.yarh.ellotv.activitytry-1.apk:/assets/fonts/ubuntu_r.ttf: 346K
    zip:/data/app/bigdig.yarh.ellotv.activitytry-1.apk:/assets/fonts/ubuntu_l.ttf: 406K
    zip:/data/app/bigdig.yarh.ellotv.activitytry-1.apk:/assets/fonts/ubuntu_r.ttf: 346K
    zip:/data/app/bigdig.yarh.ellotv.activitytry-1.apk:/assets/fonts/ubuntu_l.ttf: 406K
    zip:/data/app/bigdig.yarh.ellotv.activitytry-1.apk:/assets/fonts/ubuntu_r.ttf: 346K
    zip:/data/app/bigdig.yarh.ellotv.activitytry-1.apk:/assets/fonts/ubuntu_l.ttf: 406K
    zip:/data/app/bigdig.yarh.ellotv.activitytry-1.apk:/assets/fonts/ubuntu_r.ttf: 346K
    zip:/data/app/bigdig.yarh.ellotv.activitytry-1.apk:/assets/fonts/ubuntu_l.ttf: 406K
    zip:/data/app/bigdig.yarh.ellotv.activitytry-1.apk:/assets/fonts/ubuntu_r.ttf: 346K
    zip:/data/app/bigdig.yarh.ellotv.activitytry-1.apk:/assets/fonts/ubuntu_l.ttf: 406K
    zip:/data/app/bigdig.yarh.ellotv.activitytry-1.apk:/assets/fonts/ubuntu_r.ttf: 346K
    zip:/data/app/bigdig.yarh.ellotv.activitytry-1.apk:/assets/fonts/ubuntu_l.ttf: 406K
    zip:/data/app/bigdig.yarh.ellotv.activitytry-1.apk:/assets/fonts/ubuntu_r.ttf: 346K
    zip:/data/app/bigdig.yarh.ellotv.activitytry-1.apk:/assets/fonts/ubuntu_l.ttf: 406K
    zip:/data/app/bigdig.yarh.ellotv.activitytry-1.apk:/assets/fonts/ubuntu_r.ttf: 346K
    zip:/data/app/bigdig.yarh.ellotv.activitytry-1.apk:/assets/fonts/ubuntu_l.ttf: 406K
    zip:/data/app/bigdig.yarh.ellotv.activitytry-1.apk:/assets/fonts/ubuntu_r.ttf: 346K
    zip:/data/app/bigdig.yarh.ellotv.activitytry-1.apk:/assets/fonts/ubuntu_l.ttf: 406K
    zip:/data/app/bigdig.yarh.ellotv.activitytry-1.apk:/assets/fonts/ubuntu_r.ttf: 346K
    zip:/data/app/bigdig.yarh.ellotv.activitytry-1.apk:/assets/fonts/ubuntu_l.ttf: 406K
    zip:/data/app/bigdig.yarh.ellotv.activitytry-1.apk:/assets/fonts/ubuntu_r.ttf: 346K
    zip:/data/app/bigdig.yarh.ellotv.activitytry-1.apk:/assets/fonts/ubuntu_l.ttf: 406K
    zip:/data/app/bigdig.yarh.ellotv.activitytry-1.apk:/assets/fonts/ubuntu_r.ttf: 346K
    zip:/data/app/bigdig.yarh.ellotv.activitytry-1.apk:/assets/fonts/ubuntu_l.ttf: 406K
    zip:/data/app/bigdig.yarh.ellotv.activitytry-1.apk:/assets/fonts/ubuntu_r.ttf: 346K
    zip:/data/app/bigdig.yarh.ellotv.activitytry-1.apk:/assets/fonts/ubuntu_l.ttf: 406K
    zip:/data/app/bigdig.yarh.ellotv.activitytry-1.apk:/assets/fonts/ubuntu_l.ttf: 406K
    zip:/data/app/bigdig.yarh.ellotv.activitytry-1.apk:/assets/fonts/ubuntu_r.ttf: 346K
    zip:/data/app/bigdig.yarh.ellotv.activitytry-1.apk:/assets/fonts/ubuntu_l.ttf: 406K
    zip:/data/app/bigdig.yarh.ellotv.activitytry-1.apk:/assets/fonts/ubuntu_r.ttf: 346K
    zip:/data/app/bigdig.yarh.ellotv.activitytry-1.apk:/assets/fonts/ubuntu_l.ttf: 406K
    zip:/data/app/bigdig.yarh.ellotv.activitytry-1.apk:/assets/fonts/ubuntu_r.ttf: 346K
    zip:/data/app/bigdig.yarh.ellotv.activitytry-1.apk:/assets/fonts/ubuntu_l.ttf: 406K
    zip:/data/app/bigdig.yarh.ellotv.activitytry-1.apk:/assets/fonts/ubuntu_r.ttf: 346K
    zip:/data/app/bigdig.yarh.ellotv.activitytry-1.apk:/assets/fonts/ubuntu_l.ttf: 406K
    zip:/data/app/bigdig.yarh.ellotv.activitytry-1.apk:/assets/fonts/ubuntu_r.ttf: 346K
    zip:/data/app/bigdig.yarh.ellotv.activitytry-1.apk:/assets/fonts/ubuntu_l.ttf: 406K
    zip:/data/app/bigdig.yarh.ellotv.activitytry-1.apk:/assets/fonts/ubuntu_r.ttf: 346K
    zip:/data/app/bigdig.yarh.ellotv.activitytry-1.apk:/assets/fonts/ubuntu_l.ttf: 406K
```

Allocations:
There about 500 object allocations withe mean size of 30kb.
Also there present 2 big allocations ~10 MB each, which are caused by asset managment

```
32  char[]  10224   9   android.content.res.AssetManager.getAssetAllocations(Native Method)
21  char[]  10224   9   java.lang.String.toCharArray(String.java:1477)
```

Memory monitor shows that app consume 20 MB after start, than 24MB after first video started to play. Afterwards, consumption is slowly grows to ~50MB And does not request more memory.

Is there a way to reliably estimate how much memory app should use?

Comment: I think, your current benchmarking approach is good enough. What else do you need? You've found your big memory objects and you can work on decreasing the memory allocation for that right?

Comment: @BharathMg the thing - I dont know how to make reliable estimation about how much memmory app should consume and thus I don't know If my app requires to much space